# CWA 2011 & Content Page Template mapping

Tags: 2011, cwa

I've got a pb with a basic functionality in CWA 2011: the Content Page Template mapping.

I've got a very simple CWA 2011 web-app based on the cwa_referenceimpl.war. Nothing else, just a test web-app (will be used for automatic testing). Then I try to access a page whose page template id is "1851".

1. If I create the jsp file /WEB-INF/views/view_1851.jsp then no pb. The result is displayed correctly.
2. If I try to map this view to another jsp file using the **cd_cwa_views.xml** file (cf this documentation [link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_CWA_10&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=MappingPTsToPubIndependentViews.xml&docid=task_00C9A8E2DD474BD0BCCF9C09ABF0B810&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_00C9A8E2DD474BD0BCCF9C09ABF0B810)) then it fails. The system is still searching for the previous jsp file.

Logs:

```
24632 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.t.p.tdf.cwa.controller.Entrance - Entrance.handleLastModified: Set Last-Modified to 'Tue Jun 18 12:02:05 CEST 2013' 
24633 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.t.p.tdf.cwa.controller.Entrance - Entrance.doService: Starting handleRequest 
24634 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.t.p.tdf.cwa.controller.Entrance - Entrance.handleDispath: Forwarding request to '/WEB-INF/views/view_1851.jsp' 
24638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.t.p.tdf.cwa.controller.Entrance - Entrance.doService: Finished doService in 21ms

24638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.t.p.t.c.c.CWARequestFilter - CWARequestFilter.doFilter: Reacting on 404 return code '/cwa-standard/welink/en/corporate_communications/index.tcm' 
24638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.t.p.t.c.c.CWARequestFilter - CWARequestFilter.getWelcomeFile
```

cd_cwa_views.xml :

```
<Configuration Version="6.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_cwa_views.xsd">
    <views>
        <!-- view elements -->
        <view id="1851" path="/WEB-INF/views/demo.jsp" />
    </views>
</Configuration>
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Have you bounced the server after modifying the config?

Comment: Yes and configuration files are correctly deployed

Comment: Is this still an issue? Was it fixed?